# Android: UI Recommendations about Exit button in Applications

Tags: android, user-interface

Are UI recommendations or guidelines somewhere. I am looking for the recommendation from Google but unfortunately I can't find it.
I want to see something like "...do not use exit button in your Applications until you really need it...".
I'm sure that the exit button in android app is not good idea, in general at least. But I want to prove this idea to customers and designers.

I need links with explanations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This video will help your customers to understand: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=631T7B8HOv4

Basically, the back button is an exit button. So, there is already an exit button!

Show it to your customer and ask him if he wants to look stupid with duplicate button that takes precious space on a small screen.

His app will never look professional.

Answer (score 1):

**General Design Guidelines:**
http://developer.android.com/design/get-started/principles.html

**Best Practices for User Experience & UI:**
http://developer.android.com/training/best-ux.html

**Providing Proper Back Navigation(Something you were looking for):**
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html

Answer (score 0):

we used back button as Exit button. Generally on Back button, as per clients req we used to show the default dialog to user, "Do you want to exit app ? ".

Generally clients needs this confirmation because if we press back the app is directly exit from app. so just for confirmation to user clients want this exit dialog be there.

Answer (score 0):

No exit button is iOS philosophy, not android. I suggest you stick with device's back button rather than a UI button to exit your app while asking for confirmation via dialog box or a Toast.

Comment: Don't use an exit button on iOS either!  No mobile UI is wanting anyone to use exit buttons.  It is just an old fashioned concept.